# OpenCV cvCvtColor not linked?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm new to openCV, and I finally got it to open a window and show the webcam output.
I'm now trying to convert frames to greyscale before displaying them. Unfortunately, I get the following error every time I try to compile. `error: ‘cvCvtColor’ was not declared in this scope` I'm using the following line to compile

> g++ main.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect -o camera

Am I linking my code incorrectly? Here's the full code listing. Sorry for my formatting issues!

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


IplImage* getCameraFrame(CvCapture* &camera)
{
    IplImage *frame;
    int w, h;

    // If the camera hasn't been initialized, then open it.
    if (!camera) {
        printf("Acessing the camera ...\n");
        camera = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );
        if (!camera) {
        printf("Couldn't access the camera.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Try to set the camera resolution to 320 x 240.
    cvSetCaptureProperty(camera, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(camera, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
    // Get the first frame, to make sure the camera is initialized.
    frame = cvQueryFrame( camera );
    if (frame) {
        w = frame->width;
        h = frame->height;
        printf("Got the camera at %dx%d resolution.\n", w, h);
    }
    // Wait a little, so that the camera can auto-adjust its brightness.
    sleep(1);   // (in milliseconds)
    }

    // Wait until the next camera frame is ready, then grab it.
    frame = cvQueryFrame( camera );
    if (!frame) {
    printf("Couldn't grab a camera frame.\n");
    exit(1);
    }
return frame;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );
    IplImage* frame;

    while(1) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if( !frame ) break;

        cvCvtColor(frame, frame, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if( c == 27 ) break;
}
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error you are getting is not a linker error. It is a compiler error.

Comment: Try using **Mat** instead of **IplImage**. Also use equivalent **C++** functions(i.e. _cvtColor_ in place of _cvCvtColor_).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're using the headers for the c++ api, but code from the deprecated c-api ( please don't !! ).

```
 cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
 while(cap.IsOpened()) {
     cv::Mat f,g;
     if ( ! cap.read(f) ) break;
     cv::cvtColor(f, g, CV_RGB2GRAY);
     cv::imshow("lalala",g);
     if ( waitKey(10) == 27 ) break;
 }
 return 0;
```